# Input box for Alpha Characters only

Tags: javascript, function, input, undefined-behavior, keycode

```
  // input intials box
  var createInput = document.createElement("input");
  createInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
  createInput.setAttribute("id", "initials");
  // Max character length of 4 for people who have 2 middle names
  createInput.setAttribute("maxlength", "4");
  // Placeholder text
  createInput.setAttribute("value", "ABC");
  createInput.setAttribute("onkeydown", "return alphaOnly(event);");
  // Input my initials JMS is value is blank
  createInput.setAttribute(
    "onblur",
    "if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'JMS';}"
  );
  // Clear placeholder text onClick
  createInput.setAttribute(
    "onfocus",
    "if (this.value == 'ABC') {this.value = '';}"
  );

  createInput.textContent = "";

  questionsDiv.appendChild(createInput);

  function alphaOnly(event) {
    var key = event.keyCode;
    return (key >= 65 && key <= 90) || key == 8;
  }
```

So, I've created an input to take only initials using JavaScript. The input box loads and wors fine, but my function is not restricting the keys to 65-90 + 8 due to an error stating alphaOnly is not defined. What am I missing?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: alphaOnly is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeydown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only use letters

```
createInput.setAttribute(
    "onkeypress",
    "return ((event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || (event.charCode == 32))"
  );
```

This restricts the characters

```
  createInput.setAttribute("maxlength", "4");
```